# Mean hypotheses tests for three different samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I have three different samples and I would like to check if the means for them differ from each other statistically. I know it is not true if I run 3 different t-test between pairs. I searched and saw ANOVA test can help. But in this case I don't have any response variable (dependent) to run the ANOVA. I have just three independent variables. (3 lists of continuous variables).

It would be really appreciated if anyone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The response variable is the measurement i.e. your data.

The predictor (independent variable) is the group/sample/list to which each observation belongs.

Then you would do your ANOVA with this response variable and predictor.

Comment: So, in this situation my predictor variables are categorical (1, 2, and 3). Right?

Comment: Exactly! Depending on your software implementation, you might have to use a command like `as.factor` to clarify that $1<2$ doesn't apply and are just arbitrary labels of the groups.

Comment: Thank you very much.